# Узнать какой модуль вызвал функцию другого модуля nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this

Добрый день! Есть модуль `log.js`

```
function log(a){
    console.log(a);
}
module.exports = log;
```

где-то в проекте есть другой модуль `someFile.js`

```
const log = require("../../log.js");
log("test");
```

Как из модуля `log.js` узнать в каком модуле была вызвана его функция?

П.С.: дополнительно передаваемые переменные, типа `__filename`, не подходят, т.к. хочу уменьшить количество набираемого кода.

Comment: в общем случае никак

Comment: Если нужно - передавайте информацию об этом. Иначе выходит какое-то нарушение принципа модульности.

Comment: @Grundy, @Other, на сколько я понимаю, `this` зависит от места вызова. По такой логике, там должна быть нужная мне инфо...но найти ее не смог там(

Comment: @Дмытрык, нет ты не правильно понимаешь. И нужной тебе информации там нет. Максимум что ты можешь попробовать - бросить внутри log исключение, тут же его отловить - и попробовать по stacktrace понять что и где было вызвано

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, сделал вот так:
модуль `log.js`:

```
const path = require("path");

function write(){
    this.log = function (a){
        var base = path.parse(__filename).base;
        console.log(base,":");
        console.log(a);
    }
};

module.exports = write;
```

Модуль `someFile.js`:

```
var write = require("../my_modules/log.js");
var log = new write().log;
log("test");
```

Это, хоть, и не является решением на поставленный вопрос, но решает ту задачу, которую я решал. Думаю из кода понятно, что я хотел сделать)